# No more emulator64-x86 or emulator64-arm using sdkmanager

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sdk-manager, platform-tools

Since 1st May, i don't have any emulator64-x86 or emulator64-arm when i use the sdkmanager.

Process :

- I get the last version of android sdk tools
- i use the sdkmanager to get platform-tools, build-tools(27.0.3) and emulator using :

-> ./sdkmanager platform-tools

-> ./sdkmanager "build-tools;27.0.3"

-> ./sdkmanager --install emulator

Before the 1st May i get the binary emulator64-x86, emulator64-arm and emulator64-crash-service

Now i just have the emulator64-crash-service !

i saw there is one update on platform-tools 28.0.1 -> 28.0.2 and one on android emulator 28.0.23 -> 28.0.25

I can't get the emulator64-x86 no more.

There is a new way to get the emulator64-x86 ?

Thanks,

Jeremy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your reply,

I tried to use emulator instead of emulator64-x86 but it doesnt work for me.

After some researches, i sucessfully run my AVD with qemu-system-i386 located in emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-i386.

I got same results than before with this emulator, it seems to be good for me now.

Answer (score 0):

I was affected by this as well. Both `emulator64-x86` and `emulator64-arm` are no longer available. This is probably due to the recent [removal of QEMU1 and 32-bit Windows Support](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/05/emulator-2906-stable.html).

Try to use the `emulator` executable instead. It should launch the emulator with the correct architecture based on your created AVD.

Also see the [new headless emulator introduced in Emulator 28.1.8 Canary](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/02/emulator-2818-canary.html).